# Require perl 5.10 for only some functions

Tags: perl, version

I have a library of perl routines which I load in perl scripts with

```
do "/path/to/library";
```

Most of the functions in the library will run fine on perl >= 5.000 . 
However, one of the functions relies on perl >= 5.010 because it uses threading.

Is there a clean way to allow programs to run on, say, perl 5.008, and load the library, and only fail at runtime if they try to access the restricted function?

I tried

```
sub threadMap{
  use 5.010; #need perl 5.10 threads or else you get confusing error messages
  my %arg = @_;
```

but perl seems to evaluate 'use' on just reading the library file:

```
[js21n17][/u/jamie/bin]> ./jdPerlLib.pl 
Perl v5.10.0 required--this is only v5.8.8, stopped at ./jdPerlLib.pl line 12230.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at ./jdPerlLib.pl line 12230.
```

I will use this perlvar http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#$^V but thought I would ask for wisdom here in case that's a terrible idea.

Comment: Tried using $^V but amusingly that is not supported on 5.008, so using $] instead for now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a run-time check, you can use

```
require 5.010;
```

You can also check using

```
if ($] >= 5.010) { ... }
```

That said, 5.8 supported threads too. You should probably be using

```
require threads;
```

You can also check using

```
use Config qw( %Config );

if ($Config{usethreads}) { ... }
```

Comment: Threads are spawned correctly on 5.8, but after they start I get complaints about the coderefs I ask the threads to invoke, so I've just been forcing user to use 5.010+. I went with '$] >= 5.010'. Thanks!